# Google coding challenge not detecting int

Tags: java, casting

The point of this program is to get a long variable like "1256" and add them up digit by digit until you're left with a single digit integer. So `1 + 2 + 5 + 6 = 14`, `1 + 4 = 5`, return `5`.

When I try to verify it it gives me the error:

> public static method answer with parameters (int) not found in com.google.challenges.Answer

Could somebody please help me understand what this error means and how I can fix it?

```
package​ ​com.google.challenges;​ ​

public​ ​class​ ​Answer​ ​{​ ​​ ​​ ​
​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​public​ ​static​ ​int​ ​answer(long​ ​x)​ ​{​ ​

​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​long​ ​placeholder​ ​=​ ​0,​ ​sum​ ​=​ ​0;
​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​
​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​for(int​ ​i​ ​=​ ​1;​ ​x​ ​>​ ​0​ ​&&​ ​sum​ ​<​ ​10;​ ​i++){
            // if x = 1256 then placeholder = 1256 % 10 = 6
​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​placeholder​ ​=​ ​(long)(x​ ​%​ ​Math.pow(10,i));
​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ //1256 - 6 = 1250
            ​x​ ​-=​ ​placeholder;
​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​sum​ ​+=​ ​placeholder​ ​/​ ​(long)(Math.pow(10,​ ​i​ ​-​ ​1));
​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​if​ ​(sum​ ​>​ ​10​ ​&&​ ​x​ ​==​ ​0){
​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​i​ ​=​ ​1;
​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​x​ ​=​ ​sum;
​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​sum​ ​=​ ​0;
​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​}
​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​}
​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​return((int)sum);
​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​}
}
```

Comment: i just did this as well, strange i was trying to figure out what to do before submit. They specifically ask for long as input and int as output. But test case failed with long as input. I didn't use mod, i was a little more verbose with string splitting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's telling you that it is expecting to find a method that takes an `int` parameter, but you have declared your method to take a `long`. While you can pass an `int` to a method that's expecting a `long`, the method *signature* is different, and so the expected signature is not being found.

```
public​ ​static​ ​int​ ​answer(long​ ​x)
```

should be

```
public​ ​static​ ​int​ ​answer(int​ ​x)
```

EDIT: as per discussion in comments, this looks like an error in the test case, since the question explicitly says `long` and the answer is pre-populated with a `long` parameter.

Comment: That's how they pose it. they only ask us to edit what's inside the answer() method.

Comment: But I'll try it and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Interesting - it could be an error in the question - without seeing the rest of the question it's hard to say for sure. But certainly, that's what the error is telling you.

Comment: Ok, it's not giving me errors anymore and it's letting me know if test cases passed or failed. That seems to be it. Thank you!

Comment: you're welcome - I'm still curious about whether there was an error in the original challenge though :)

Comment: I'll send a bug report.

Comment: @kcbeard thanks for the info - sounds like an error on google's part alright - I guess either Eric didn't file his bug report, or they ignored it (hard to imagine that happening, right? ;-)

Comment: @CupawnTae I guess so, or maybe they want you to figure out the solution based on the test. In test driven development the test is a use case for product integrity. The word problem may have been incorrect so the correct answer to the solution would be int returning int. And the test is there to verify product integrity. Makes sense in hind sight. But I found it to be a fun test. I never wrote java before, lol but i did it last night!

Answer (score 0):

> public static method answer with parameters (int) not found in `com.google.challenges.Answer`

Try to use int as a method parameter. The solution processing expects the method to require an int parameter.

Correct method head:

`public​ ​static​ ​int​ ​answer(int​ ​x)`

Answer (score 0):

For those curious this is answer I used which passed all the test cases.

```
package com.google.challenges; 

public class Answer {   
    public static int answer(int x) { 

        int placeholder = 0, sum = 0;

        for(int i = 1; x > 0 ; i++){
            placeholder = x % (int)(Math.pow(10,i));
            x -= placeholder;
            sum += placeholder / (int)(Math.pow(10, i - 1));
            if (sum > 10 && x == 0){
                i = 0;
                x = sum;
                sum = 0;
                continue;
            }
            if (sum < 10 && x == 0){
            break;
            }
        }
    return((int)sum);
    }
}
```